# Eclipse Strange Errors

Tags: java, eclipse

my eclipse  galileo installation has started giving me problems all of a sudden.

yesterday I was unable to start my tomct6 server and today I am unable to create a dynamic web project.

I get the following error

```
    The selected wizard could not be started.
  Plug-in "org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.project.facet.WebProjectWizard".
  java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My eclipse is shared with my colleagues, is that an issue ? Also I recently installed m2 sonatype plug in for maven 2.

Comment: The stack trace of the NPE might give a clue ...

Comment: I had the same issue. Galileo, unable to start tomcat, unable to create dynamic web project and recently installed m2 sonatype. I followed the suggestion below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you updated from eclipse recently? From some quick [googling](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Plug-in+%22org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui%22+was+unable+to+instantiate+class+%22org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.project.facet.WebProjectWizard%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) it seems like mixing Galileo with updates for Helios in some modules is causing this error message. I would suggest to download eclipse Helios and point to your current workspace.